# Call C# method inside a class file from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to call a C# function which is inside a specific class file by javascript?

My Function is like this

```
    public static void PrintPDF()
    {
    }
```

and this function is inside a class file `XSLTHelper`
In C# I can call this function by `XSLTHelper.PrintPDF();`.
Is there is any way to do the same from javascript?

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to call a server side function (C#) from a client side function (javascript)? If yes, you should learn what is a webservice.

Comment: @poiuytrez:Thanks for pointing me to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ajax call as below:

```
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "PageName.aspx/PrintPDF",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",

      success: function (msg) {
           if (msg.d == 'Success') {

            }

        }

   });
```

Your function needs to have attribute as follow:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery and Ajax to call an action Method which can call the PrintPDF function?